# Update a UITextField in a not visible section of UIScrollView without focusing it?

Tags: objective-c

I have to update the text of a UITextField in a not visible section of my UIScrollView but, when I try it, it move the scrollview to it. I don't want this but how can I update my not visible uitextfield without move the scrollview?
Thanks,
Alleria

Comment: The code is banal:         activityAtEOBTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f", [activityAtEOBTextField.text doubleValue] * 0.037];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear what exactly you are trying to do, but I am guessing its either of these, and I am posting them below.

Declare that textField as a property. `UITextField *myTextField`

If you want to edit that, you can use `[myTextField becomeFirstResponder]` . This will bring up a keyboard for you to type and enter details, and then you can `resignFirstResponder`.

If you just want that textField to contain some text, you can just use

```
self.myTextField.text = @"Some Text";
```

Comment: I have resolved it! I just see that my problem was the focus on the UITextField in the invisible area of UIScrollView, in fact when I updated this my scrollView scrolls to it. I simple do [textField resignFirstResponder]; and nothing else :)